# Get a Shapefile Geometry Type

Tags: arcgis-desktop, python, arcpy, arcgis-9.3

I am making a python code for Arcgis9.3. In this code I have an input feature and I create a Output feature. I want that the output feature is the same geometry type as the input feature. At the moment my code to create the output feature is :

```
gp.CreateFeatureclass("C:/Users/Desktop/Test/", NameOutFC, "POLYLINE")
```

But I would like to get the input feature geometry type and use it to create my output feature :

```
gp.CreateFeatureclass("C:/Users/Desktop/Test/", NameOutFC, GeometryLikeInput)
```

I found the code with ArcPy :

```
desc = arcpy.Describe('C:/shapefile.shp')
geometryType = desc.shapeType

if geometryType == 'polygon':
print 'Polygon'
elif geometryType == 'point'
```

But I can't use it with arcgis9.3.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [Geometry object](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.3/index.cfm?TopicName=The_geometry_object) which is available even in 9.3.

[image]

The [.pdf file](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.3/pdf/Geoprocessor_93.pdf) for Geoprocessor model in 9.3

The code sample:

```
rows = gp.SearchCursor("D:/St_Johns/data.gdb/roads")
row = rows.Next()
while row:
    print row.Type
```

Alternative way is to use [Describe](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.3/index.cfm?TopicName=Describe_method) method where you could use ShapeType:

```
import arcgisscripting
gp = arcgisscripting.create(9.3)
gp.workspace = r"C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Reference Systems"
fc = r"C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Reference Systems\utm.shp"
dsc = gp.describe(fc)
print "ShapeType: \n" + str(dsc.ShapeType)
```

Which gives you `Polygon`

Comment: Yes but in this case i have to chexk all the feature in my shapefile and the return geometry type is the geometry type of each feature. So i am looking for a code which return the geometry of the shapefile directly without reading each row and retrun each feature geometry.

Comment: Then just add a counter in the code and use the while counter < 2 in the code. Shapefile can store only one type of geometry, so you are done when you figure out the geometry type of the first feature.

Comment: @Panvjim0, I've updated my answer to include a cleaner way to access the shape type of a feature class.