# Get geometry type from Feature Collection for every row

Tags: python, geojson

I want to get geometry type for every row (like point, linestring, polygon etc.) from GeoJSON data.

This is my code for reading data.

```
import argparse
import geopandas as gpd
import os
import sys
import shapely

data = gpd.read_file('data.geojson')
for index, row in data.iterrows():
    print('Data: ', row['geometry'])
```

I have tried these solutions. But con not works.
[Get a Shapefile Geometry Type](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/94558/get-a-shapefile-geometry-type)

Do you have any idea?

This is my 'data.geojson' file.

```
{
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [102.0, 0.5]
      },
      "properties": {
        "prop0": "value0"
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "LineString",
        "coordinates": [
          [102.0, 0.0], [103.0, 1.0], [104.0, 0.0], [105.0, 1.0]
        ]
      },
      "properties": {
        "prop0": "value0",
        "prop1": 0.0
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            [100.0, 0.0], [101.0, 0.0], [101.0, 1.0],
            [100.0, 1.0], [100.0, 0.0]
          ]
        ]
      },
      "properties": {
        "prop0": "value0",
        "prop1": { "this": "that" }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The `GeoSeries` class in `geopandas` package has `geom_type` attribute which gives you type of features geometry. Please review link: [Overview of Attributes and Methods](http://geopandas.org/data_structures.html#attributes).

```
import geopandas as gpd

data = gpd.read_file('data.geojson')
data.geom_type # Here, geom_type returns GeoSeries

# OUTPUT:
# 0         Point
# 1    LineString
# 2       Polygon
# dtype: object
```

Or you can use `geom_type` attribute to get type of any geometry in `shapely` package.

```
import geopandas as gpd

data = gpd.read_file('data.geojson')
for index, row in data.iterrows():
    print(row['geometry'].geom_type) # geom_type returns string, like 'Point' etc.

# OUTPUT:
# Point
# LineString
# Polygon
```

Comment: Thank you very much Dear @Kadir Şahbaz. The second method best for me. Thank you again :)